# React Native Image https url not show image in lower api 23

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react native 0.61.0 version. react 16.9.0 version. our server enable TLS 1.2 and 1.3. api request work fine on below api 23 but only image are not show in image component.

here is my sample image code

```
//_renderImage = (image: any, index: number) => {
_renderImage = (image, index) => {
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const { onPress, customSlide } = this.props;
const offset = { marginLeft: index === -1 ? -width : 0 };
const imageStyle = [styles.image, { width }, offset];

if (customSlide) {
  return customSlide({ item: image, style: imageStyle, index, width });
}

const imageObject = typeof image === 'string' ? { uri: image } : image;
const imageComponent = (
 <Image key={index} source={imageObject} style={[imageStyle]} resizeMethod="resize" resizeMode="cover" />
);

if (onPress) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      style={[imageStyle, offset]}
      onPress={() => onPress && onPress({ image, index })}
      delayPressIn={200}
    >
      {imageComponent}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

return imageComponent;
```

};

```
 <ImageSliders
          loop
          autoPlayWithInterval={3000}
          images={images} // here i pass image url array
        />
```

in above android api 23 it work fine, but api 23 and below it not working, any one have any idea  why this happen.

Comment: May be typeof image === 'string' condition getting false or onPress prop condition false. Can you check and share what's the value in image uri? and where _renderImage calling? Share some more piece of code

Comment: this is output of imageObject. 11-07 16:12:50.423 9723-9771/com.runitpass I/ReactNativeJS: image {"uri":"https://runitpassapi.com/images/1603627007994.png"}
11-07 16:12:50.435 9723-9771/com.runitpass I/ReactNativeJS: out out image {"uri":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/164595/pexels-photo-164595.jpeg"}

Comment: Image uri is looking fine. remove style from Image just for checking or just use style={{wdith:xx, height: xx}} only

Comment: do as command, still get same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
Change style={[imageStyle]} to style={imageStyle}
```

Another change might be doing like

```
return onPress ? (
    <TouchableOpacity> 
      ......
      {imageComponent}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : null;
}
```

Comment: this also try, same result.